# Open multiple file directories on python

Tags: python, directory

I would like to loop over and access my files of type .bin that each contain three values of type double (pitch, yaw, roll).
So far I was able to access one file only by using `with open('annotations/01/frame_00004_pose.bin', 'rb') as fid:`

I am aware that I need to change that line of code for my loop to work properly. I am just unsure as to how I can proceed. So my file is `annotations` having 01-24 files each having many other files of type .bin

Here is what I have done so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

pyr = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['pitch','yaw','roll'])
with os.scandir('annotations') as entries:
    for i in entries:
        with open('annotations/01/frame_00004_pose.bin', 'rb') as fid:
            data_array = np.fromfile(fid, np.float32)
        para = data_array[3:]
        pyr = pyr.append({'pitch':para[0],'yaw':para[1],'roll':para[2]},ignore_index = True)
print(pyr)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `glob` module . a simple Google search on python glob module will get you results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use glob is a good idea, see it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import os
import glob

pyr = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['pitch','yaw','roll'])
entries = glob.glob('annotations/**/*.bin', recursive=True)
for entry in entries:
    with open(entry, 'rb') as fid:
        data_array = np.fromfile(fid, np.float32)
    para = data_array[3:]
    pyr = pyr.append({'pitch':para[0],'yaw':para[1],'roll':para[2]},ignore_index = True)
print(pyr)
```